# VBA, .NumberFormat , quotes within quotes

Tags: vba

I am getting type mismatch on formatting my paste to another sheet. 
I believe it is because of "" within the custom format.

Is there a way around this?

Thanks.

`rFiltered.Copy Sheets("Step 4").Range("D10").NumberFormat = "_-* #,##0_-;-* #,##0_-;_-* " - "??_-;_-@_-"`

Answer (score 0):

Use a library that provides variable interpolation so that you don't need to embed naked quotes.  I wrote one for myself I call [Layout](https://github.com/SteveLaycock/Layout) because I got fed up with assembling strings with multiple variables.

Using my Layout template I would write your code as

rFiltered.Copy Sheets("Step 4").Range("D10").NumberFormat = Fmt("*-* #,##0*-;-* #,##0_-;*-* {dq} - {dq}??*-;*-@*-")